# How to change the output of the JSON array in an object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I have an issue regarding the API JSON output. I am getting stuck into JSON output when in a loop, it is making its own index when i am forcing the array format to change into the index array.

PHP Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name,fname,address FROM user_management";
$array = array();

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$i=1;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $array=["message"=>"success"];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $array[] = ["Hello" => $row];

 } 

} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
 //echo implode(',', $array);
 // Take output array glue it with the
echo json_encode($array);
$conn->close();
?>
```

I am getting the response as:

```
{
  "message": "success",
  "0": {
    "Hello": {
      "name": "harjot",
      "fname": "tejinder",
      "address": "noida"
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "Hello": {
      "name": "regret",
      "fname": "egegrregeger",
      "address": "gegreg"
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "Hello": {
      "name": "harjot1",
      "fname": "harjot2",
      "address": "noida"
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "Hello": {
      "name": "har",
      "fname": "har1",
      "address": "Punjab"
    }
  }
}
```

I want the response as without the 0,1,2,3 that array is making on its own.Is there a way to access the index of an arrays?

**Expected output:**

```
{   "message": "success",
    "Hello": {
      "name": "harjot",
      "fname": "tejinder",
      "address": "noida"   },
    "Hello1": {
      "name": "regret",
      "fname": "egegrregeger",
      "address": "gegreg"   },
    "Hello2": {
      "name": "harjot1",
      "fname": "harjot2",
      "address": "noida"   },
    "Hello3": {
      "name": "har",
      "fname": "har1",
      "address": "Punjab"
    }   
}
```

Comment: change from `$array[] = ["Hello" => $row];`  to `$array["Hello".$i] = $row;`

Comment: Output is changed but still getting the arrays own indexes with 0,1,2,3 in keys. How to remove them?

Comment: show your code in screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was having declaration of `$i` for maintaining counter but you were not using it.

**Change this:**

```
$array[] = ["Hello" => $row];
```

**This:**

```
$array["Hello".$i] = $row;
```

Also add `$i++;` for maintaining and increasing counter value.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php //
$sql = "SELECT name,fname,address FROM user_management";
$array = array();

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$i=1;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $array=["message"=>"success"];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $array["Hello".$i] = $row;//added line here
    $i++;//added this line to increment counter everytime.
 } 

} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
 //echo implode(',', $array);
 // Take output array glue it with the
echo json_encode($array);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $array["Hello".$i++] = $row;

 }
```

OR

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $array["Hello".$i] = $row;
    $i++;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks dude, Again Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $array=["message"=>"success"];
    $index = "";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array["Hello" . $index] = $row;
        $index = $index ? ($index + 1) : 1;
    }
}
```